# How do I fix this error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've been getting this error every now and then, and once I thought it was fixed, it just came back:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.wolfixfinal/com.example.wolfixfinal.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.wolfixfinal/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.wolfixfinal/com.example.wolfixfinal.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I've made two or three other questions about this topic and it's getting annoying. I've tried removing the gradle and .gradle folder, removing the .idea folder and then rebuilding the project. I don't know what to do anymore.

How do I keep this from not happening, is it something I have to do all the time everytime I see this error.

Comment: You should add Manifest.xml and build.gradle

Comment: This has something to do with the Manifest file, because of MAIN and LAUNCHER. Can you post the code from your Manifest file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure than only ONE of your activities has the LAUNCHER and MAIN properties in your Manifest file. This file can be found under Android Project view: `app > manifests > AndroidManifest.xml`. The one you want to boot in is the one that should have these properties.

Like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:exported="true">

        <!--This will be the starting activity you want-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

NOT like this (2 activities in the manifest both have:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

):

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I'll make sure to use it wisely. Once I'm able to use the PC where I keep my projects, I'll apply this and, if it works, accept this answer.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan!

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer, even though I haven't tested it because I can't find my files...